# IntelliJ importing class settings issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea

http://pastebin.com/nXpVmKRQ

http://pastebin.com/pDamG5Fr

http://pastebin.com/0EKb2fSP

The three links above are of a binary search tree assignment I am working on. All three files are in my `src` folder in my project. However, when I try to run `Problem2.java` it says:

> "cannot resolve symbol 'AbstractTree'".

Also, in `Problem3.java` it says the same thing:

> -- "cannot resolve symbol 'BST'"

Can anyone run these files on their IDE (preferably IntelliJ) & let me know if this is a problem with my project settings or if I made an error in my code.

Comment: This looks like homework, you should contact your TAs or professors about this instead.

Comment: @bernlim I graduated 4 years ago. I'm working from a java book. but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all your classes are in the default package. A class in the default package cannot import another class in the same package. You need to put your class in a non-default package.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? What exactly directory structure did you have? Did you add an 'import' statement importing your class?